# How to make small updates of state (nested property) in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Consider a simple component of a key trainer app. Before growing into a complicated app, it can have the following state:

```
constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
        task: {
            line: 'fjj jfjjf fj fffj fjjfj jffj f',
            position: 0,
            mistakeAtCurrentPosition: false
        }
    };
    ...
}
```

Now I have a key press handler and so when user pressed it correctly I'd like to change

```
{
    task: {
        line: 'fjj jfjjf fj fffj fjjfj jffj f',
        position: 10,
        mistakeAtCurrentPosition: false
    }
};
```

to

```
{
    task: {
        line: 'fjj jfjjf fj fffj fjjfj jffj f',
        position: 11,
        mistakeAtCurrentPosition: false
    }
};
```

This is too verbose and fragile:

```
this.setState(prevState => {
    return {
        task: {
            line: prevState.task.line,
            position: prevState.task.position + 1,
            mistakeAtCurrentPosition: false
        }
    }
})
```

I know that [state updates are merged](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-are-merged), but as far as I can see, they are merged only on the first level of nesting, like if my state were

```
{
    line: 'fjj jfjjf fj fffj fjjfj jffj f',
    position: 11,
    mistakeAtCurrentPosition: false
};
```

I could do

```
this.setState(prevState => {
    return {
        position: prevState.task.position + 1,
    }
})
```

(but if I try

```
this.setState(prevState => {
    return {
        task: {
            position: prevState.task.position + 1,
        }
    }
})
```

the app is messed up, looks like `state.task.line` is not defined anymore)

But I created a nested `task` property for a reason (there'll be other tasks etc), so how do I update only the `state.task.position` bit?

I've also tried

```
this.setState(prevState => {
    prevState.task.position++;
    return prevState;
})
```

but the app fails to compile this way.

PS actually, the last one sometimes compliles, but doesn't work in a reproducible manner. adiga has noted that `prevState` is a reference to the current state and current state should not be muted, thus this approach should be avoided.

Comment: this.setState(prevState => {...prevState, task: {...prevState.task, position: prevState.task.position + 1}}

Comment: @F.bernal yeap, adiga has already suggested this in an answer, I'll try that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
this.setState(prevState => {
    return {
        ...prevState, 
        task: { ...prevState.task, position: prevState.task.position + 1 }
    }
})
```

Comment: actually, the `...prevState,` bit doesn't seem to be needed exactly because of  https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-are-merged

Comment: Yes, if `task` is the only property in `state`, the second way should be fine

Comment: No, I mean even if `task` is not the only property, see the link. I've already tested that (added a `more` property to `state`, displayed it and check what happens when the `state` is updated in the seconde way; docs don't lie)

Comment: You're right. I'm just a beginner in react and I assumed if an updater function instead of an object, then shallow merging won't work..